# Which Salesforce web APIs are available to Group Edition?

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, soap, rest

I've been writing a REST API-based service and testing on a Developer Edition org user and it's been working fine, but it stops working for a Salesforce user with a Group Edition org. I get this error: `API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: The REST API is not enabled for this Organization`.

Which API will work on the most number of org editions, including a Group Edition?

There must be some API that does this because Yesware seems to be doing it. I have a Group Edition account and hooked up Yesware **without** installing their app on Salesforce and they are able to create Tasks for existing Accounts.

Note that I am not looking to release an app in AppExchange (no Apex code). I only want to OAuth a user and then create/update records to their Salesforce account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Free-for-all API access is only allowed on Enterprise, Developer, Unlimited, and Performance Edition. Sometimes, Professional Edition clients can pay extra to obtain API access (the policy tends to fluctuate over time).

ISV's (Independent Service Vendors) can apply for a "client ID", which grants them API access to orgs that otherwise would not have access (Group Edition and Professional Edition). They can only use this client ID in the context of their application, or their access can be revoked. A security review is executed before they are granted this "client ID" to make sure their services are secure, and will not compromise client data. Connected Apps can also be granted access after a security review, which is the latest authentication model for ISV's to integrate their services with clients that use salesforce.com.

Comment: Just to be clear, a "Connected App" contains Apex code, right? It's the model where the user "installs" an app from AppExchange?

Comment: A connected app is typically an external (non-Apex) app, using APIs. It connects to the platform.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: API access is not normally supported in GE and PE orgs. However, after your app passes the security review, you’re eligible to use some APIs for building composite applications.

API Access to GE and PE:

Web Services (SOAP) --->    Yes, with token

Apex methods exposed as Web services (SOAP) ---->   No

Web services (REST) --->    Yes, with connected app consumer whitelisting

Apex methods exposed as Web services (REST) --->    Yes, with connected app consumer whitelisting

Chatter REST API --->   Yes

Metadata API --->   Yes, with token

Bulk API --->   No

Data Loader tool (uses SOAP Web services) --->  No, can’t set the token

SOURCE: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm