# Connected app to push the lead/contact to salesforce.com Group edition or Professional edition

Tags: isv, connected-apps

We have our connected apps which works for salesforce.com Enterprise and unlimited edition but does not work for Group edition or Professional edition. After following the document we got to know that this is only possible through ISV partner program . in sort [Which Salesforce web APIs are available to Group Edition?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54169/which-salesforce-web-apis-are-vailable-to-group-editiona).

Question 1: If this is the only way to push the data to salesforce.com GE/PE edition then how much we have to pay to get the Client ID. (Monthly / Yearly).

Question 2 : We are not going to host our app in app exchange for now just our connected app should be able to push the data to salesforce.com GE/PE edition . could you please put some light what are the steps to follow to get the client id.

Please let us know if you need more detail on this. Thank you

Pravanjan

Comment: Are you an ISV building an app to sell to customers, or are you building the app for your own company's use?

Comment: Thanks for reply  @metadaddy . The connected app is for our company's use. We are in  answering business every time a customer get call for him/her our web app take message for him and if  the message  is eligible for lead we are pushing it to customer's  crm (eg : salesforce) . As there is a api level restriction in GE/PE we are looking a way to push the message intake to these account type.  Just a note : The connected app is used inside our web application and which authenticate the customer using  AUTH 2 flow and grant access for required api to communicate with SFDC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [sign up as an ISV Partner](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/appvendors) (free of charge), then you can pay for the security review (currently $2700 for paid apps), get the client ID, and access GE/PE orgs via the APIs. You don't need to list your app publicly in the AppExchange if you don't want to.

Your best course of action would be to discuss the details with an ISV rep after you've signed up.

Comment: Thank you @metadaddy . I am following with ISV rep  will update the thread once i get the details.